# What's up with the two Elves outside Phillipa's House?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Okay, Phillipa, I realize that the last time I sent Geralt barging into your house, he interrupted some casual S&M between you and your apprentice, and the time before that, I interrupted a sensual massage of some sort.

But was it *really* necessary to post two Scoia'tel outside your room to prevent future interruptions? *All* of my available quests require speaking to you, but your two doormen never seem to take a break, and I've been trying to reach you for several in-game days now.

Did you want my help curing Saskia and breaking the Curse, or not?

What's the deal with the Elven Doormen? When do they take a break? How can I get in to speak with Phillipa the Sorceress?

Comment: @Matthew - they are un-interactable, and completely block the door.

Comment: @Matthew, you remind me of someone who once made me an offer I couldn't refuse..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not Phillipa's house. That's where Saskia is recuperating. Philipa's house is in the same part of the town as the blacksmith.

Comment: Hunh. The quest marker is pointing towards that house... but then again, the quest marker has lied to me before. Let's see if I can't find the real house, then.